# PetaPoco query with typed parameters

Tags: petapoco

Using PetaPoco, how do i call stored procedure with typed parameters?
in c# i do it like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = email;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [documentation](http://www.toptensoftware.com/Categories/PetaPoco) for further details but here is an extract.

http://www.toptensoftware.com/Articles/114/PetaPoco-What-s-new-in-v4-0

> **Support for IDbParameters as SQL arguments**
>
> PetaPoco now supports directly passing IDbParameter objects to a
>   query. This is handy if PetaPoco doesn't correctly map a property.
>
> For example the SQL Server driver doesn't handle assigning DbNull to a
>   VarBinary column unless the parameter is configured with the correct
>   type. To work around this you can now do this:

`databaseQuery.Execute("insert into temp1 (t) values (@0)", 
                 new SqlParameter() { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarBinary, Value = DbNull.Value });`

> One interesting side effect of this is that
>   you can also return an IDbParameter from the PetaPoco.IMapper
>   interface to globally override PetaPoco's default parameter mapping
>   functionality.

Comment: I've just added a pull request to PetaPoco (https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/pull/272) to correct a bug for when one IDbParameter is used multiple times in a query. The expansion of one parameter to many inside PetaPoco causes an error because the parameter is not a value type.