# Can I define custom type mapping for parameters and fields in PetaPoco?

Tags: c#, postgresql, petapoco

I'm currently trying to pick a C# ORM to use with my PostgreSQL database, and I'm interested in the micro-ORMs, since they allow me to better utilize the power of Postgres(and since full blown ORMs are hard to configure. While Dapper simply works, trying to deal with NHibernate has left a forehead shaped dent in my screen...)

Anyways, currently PetaPoco has the lead, but there is one feature I need and can't figure if it has(to be fair - I couldn't find it in the other ORMs either) - mapping of custom types.

My PostgreSQL database uses the hstore and Postgis extensions, which define custom types. I don't expect any ORM to support those types(it's hard enough to find one that supports PostgreSQL!) but I want to be able to provide my own mappers for them, so when I get them as columns or send them as parameters PetaPoco will automatically use my mappers.

Is this even possible? The closest I could find is [IDbParameter support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812153/petapoco-query-with-typed-parameters), but those are built-in types and I need to write mappers for extension types that are not part of [the list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dbtype.aspx)...

Comment: NPoco is a fork of PetaPoco which contains a way to customize mappings. I have already done the work for PostgreSQL including HStore and DateTimeOffset. Ping me @schotime on twitter for more info.

Comment: You can also checkout this GIST for basic sample: https://gist.github.com/schotime/6314871

Comment: @Schotime I can't use NPoco, since it uses npgsql2 which is not in the NuGet Gallery(the npgsql in the Gallery is version 2.<something>, but it's still called `npgsql` so NPoco won't recognize it). Still, your gist was very helpful, as it gave me a direction to find (half) a solution that can be implemented in the original PetaPoco.

Comment: I use the Npgsql (2.0.12.1) from NuGet with NPoco out of the box and it works fine. What are the issues you are having so I can look to solve them?

Comment: `Unhandled Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider 'Npgsql2'.`

Comment: `<DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>`

Comment: and.... `<add name="Conn" connectionString="Server=;Database=;User Id=;Password=;Use Extended Types=true" providerName="Npgsql"/>`

Comment: then... `IDatabase db = new Database("Conn");`

Answer (score 2):

Based on Schotime's comment, I came with half a solution - how to parse the `hstore` from the query results into the object. I'm leaving this question open in case someone wants to get the other solution.

I need to define my own mapper. Obviously I want to use PetaPoco's default mapping for regular types, so it's only natural to inherit `PetaPoco.StandardMapper` - but that won't work, because `StandardMapper` implements `PetaPoco.IMapper`'s fields without the `virtual` attribute - so I can't override them(I can only overshadow them, but that's not really helping).

What I did instead was to implement `IMapper` directly, and delegate regular types to an instance of `PetaPoco.IMapper`:

```
public class MyMapper:PetaPoco.IMapper{
    private PetaPoco.StandardMapper standardMapper=new PetaPoco.StandardMapper();
    public PetaPoco.TableInfo GetTableInfo(Type pocoType){
        return standardMapper.GetTableInfo(pocoType);
    }
    public PetaPoco.ColumnInfo GetColumnInfo(PropertyInfo pocoProperty){
        return standardMapper.GetColumnInfo(pocoProperty);
    }
    public Func<object, object> GetFromDbConverter(PropertyInfo TargetProperty, Type SourceType){
        if(TargetProperty.PropertyType==typeof(HStore)){
            return (x)=>HStore.Create((string)x);
        }
        return standardMapper.GetFromDbConverter(TargetProperty,SourceType);
    }
    public Func<object, object> GetToDbConverter(PropertyInfo SourceProperty){
        if(SourceProperty.PropertyType==typeof(HStore)){
            return (x)=>((HStore)x).ToSqlString();
        }
        return standardMapper.GetToDbConverter(SourceProperty);
    }
}
```

The `HStore` object is constructed similarly to the one in [Schotime's gist](https://gist.github.com/schotime/6314871).

I also need to register the mapper:

```
PetaPoco.Mappers.Register(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MainClass)),new MyMapper());
PetaPoco.Mappers.Register(typeof(HStore),new MyMapper());
```

Now, all of this works perfectly when I read from the query - but not when I write query parameters(even though I defined `GetToDbConverter`. It seems my mapper simply isn't called when I'm writing query parameters. Any idea how to do that?